# JavaScript error as unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to save my file but getting error on append the default HTML base structure.

```js
$('#saveHTML').click(function() {
    var html = $('#editor').val();
    // Append the default HTML base structure
    html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>HTML File</title></head><body>' + html + '</body></html>`;
    // Write your code to save HTML file here.
    // Generate a random filename
    var filename = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
    // Create a temporary element
    var tmpElement = document.createElement('a');
    // Set temporary element attributes
    tmpElement.download = filename + '.html';
    tmpElement.href = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(html);
    // Simulate click on the temporary element
    tmpElement.click();
    // Remove the temporary element
    document.body.removeChild(tmpElement);
    // Show success message
    alert('HTML file saved successfully!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
<button id="saveHTML">Click</button>
```

What I am doing wrong here?

I am getting below error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input at line no 3*

Comment: I get `NotFoundError: Node.removeChild: The node to be removed is not a child of this node`. Can you fix it?

Comment: sorry not getting can you please help me here

Comment: Click "Run code snippet" and then click the button.

Comment: @jabaa for me it is showing different error in the console

Comment: @Jabaa unexpected end of input while appending in default html structure

Comment: I would say you have a typo in your code that isn't in your question. `document.body.removeChild(tmpElement);` can't work because you don't append it before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251818/discussion-between-mr-m-and-jabaa).

Answer (score 0):

I found two bugs:

1. You made an error trying to use template string and string concatenation. It's correct usage is shown on line 4.
2. You forgot to append the `a` tag to the body. See line 10.
   Good luck!

```js
$('#saveHTML').click(function() {
    var html = $('#editor').val();
    // Append the default HTML base structure
    html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>HTML File</title></head><body>${html}</body></html>`;
    // Write your code to save HTML file here.
    // Generate a random filename
    var filename = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
    // Create a temporary element
    var tmpElement = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(tmpElement);
    // Set temporary element attributes
    tmpElement.download = filename + '.html';
    tmpElement.href = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(html);
    // Simulate click on the temporary element
    tmpElement.click();
    // Remove the temporary element
    document.body.removeChild(tmpElement);
    // Show success message
    alert('HTML file saved successfully!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
<button id="saveHTML">Click</button>
```